# Can Windows be installed on a Lenovo Chromebook ThinkPad e11?

Tags: windows, chromebook

Can Windows be installed on this Lenovo Chromebook ThinkPad e11?

If so, I would like to know where the security fence is.

Comment: What does your google research show?

Comment: Security screw? Security fence? Neither are shown in the hardware maintenance service manual. https://thinkpads.com/support/hmm/hmm_pdf/tp_11e_yoga11e_hmm_en_sp40f29949.pdf

Answer (score 1):

[Your five year old Chromebook](https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/thinkpad/11e-and-chromebooks/20GF-MT/p/22TP2TX152E20GF), and indeed nearly all Chromebooks, won't meet the [minimum requirements Microsoft says](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4028142/windows-windows-10-system-requirements) any Windows 10 machine must meet. Instead, you might consider [Lubuntu's Lxqt](https://lubuntu.me/) variant or [Peppermint OS](https://peppermintos.com/).